# How to multiply result of predicate in prolog?

Tags: prolog, predicate

How to multiply or divide returned result of predicate in prolog?

For example, I have predicate which counts how many times some element appears in list. It looks like this :

```
elemCount(X, [X|T], N)
```

where X is the element, [X|T] is the list and N is count.
When my input is **(3,[1,2,3],X)** I get the result **X=1**. But is it possible to multiply result, for example, with 2 and instead of **X=1** get **X=2.**
I tried something like this

```
elemCount(X,[X|T],2*N)
```

but without success.

Comment: `elemCount(X, [X|T], N), N1 is N*2.` And `N1` is instantiated with the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunatley this does not work when I need to compare the result of elemCount predicate. Forexample when I create predicate `compare([H|T],A):- elemCount(H,[H|T],X),elemCount(H,A,X)`, this return ture if list [[H|T],A] has the same count of each element as in list A, but I need to check if list [H|T] has each element three times more then list A. So in this case `compare([H|T],A):- elemCount(H,[H|T],X),N is X*3,elemCount(H,A,X)`gives me an error `Singleton variables: [N]`

Comment: You get an warning not because what I showed you is wrong, but because the logic of your code is wrong. What I showed is the correct way to get `N*2` if you have `elemCount(X, [X|T], N)`. Your logic should be, `elemCount(H, [H|T], X), N is X // 3, elemCount(H, A, N).` Note that you said, *`[H|T]` has 3 times more than list `A`*, so you need `N is X // 3` not `N is X * 3`. And we're assuming here that `X` is divisible by `3`. If you really mean, *`A` has 3 times more than list `[H|T]`* then the logic is, `elemCount(H, [H|T], X), N is X*3, elemCount(H, A, N).` "Singleton" means value not used.